# How to add inline visualforce page in edit view of contact object?

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, detail-page

I have a requirement to add inline visualforce page in the detail page and also this inline visualforce page should be add in edit view. I don't know it is possible or not. Here is the link that say it is [available](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS). But I was not able to achieve this. Please help me to out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The idea was flagged as delivered to close the comments for the idea. This is a relatively unusual situation, but the idea has not been "delivered." The comment from the PM basically suggests that they'll release a new idea when they figure out the delivery mechanism. That said, (#safeharbor applies here) it'll probably be a Lightning-only feature, exposed as Lightning components you can just add directly to the page layout. You might try [@asksalesforce](https://twitter.com/asksalesforce) and see if they have more information they can share...